# Core Data With NSData Attribute

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nsarray, nspredicate

I am working on a `Core Data`  based iOS application , in which i stored an array strings in coredata as `NSData`(binary data).
While  fetching  the data , how can i write  a `NSPredicate` which will only retrieve the result with  `NSData` value contain given string .

if `name` attribute is a string then i can write a predicate like below.

```
NSString *inputName = @"bbb";
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = %@",inputName];
```

my question is
what will be the predicate if `name` is `NSData` and this `NSData` from

```
NSArray *anArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"aaa",@"bbb",@"ccc",nil];
NSData *arrayData = [NSArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:anArray];
```

`arrayData` is stored as `name` attribute in Core Data .

I hope this information is enough to understand  my problem. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the reason behind storing a string as `NSData`?

Comment: @Akshay - for eg: i have a supervisor filed , it associated to number of employees..these employe names will be an array of string. core data not supporting NSArray so i converted it to NSData and stored in core data..

Comment: @Akshay and i m not storing string as NSData otherwise array string is stored as data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the answer ..converted `NSArray` to `NSSet` and store it in entity

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question and subsequent comments correctly, and you are using an array stored as data to represent a hierarchical relationship then you are clearly not using Core Data as designed.

Instead, I recommend you create a separate entity to represent the employees and then set up a relationship between them and the supervisor?

Although it's not iOS specific, this [tutorial by Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSPersistentDocumentTutorial/01_Task/task.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002829-SW1) demonstrates that very concept.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, I think you need to revisit your schema. If you have a one-many relationship between Supervisor & Employee (Many employees can have the same supervisor), you should create an Entity `Employee`, and add an attribute supervisorID to it. Then you can query your Employee table with something like- `where supervisorID="123"`.

If you cannot redesign your schema, you can convert NSData to NSString & save it in CoreData using `-initWithData:encoding:`.

HTH,

Akshay